# R spread columns with a specific pattern

Tags: r, dplyr, spread

Got a data.frame with a column like this:

```
Column_1
AAA
B
BBB
AAA_FACE
CCC
BBB_AAA
```

I want to spread the column into new columns (but not for all my unique values, because then I would get very, very much columns), but only for the values containing a specific pattern: "AAA".

After spreading the values, I want to make them binary, So ideally my new data.frame looks like this:

```
AAA    AAA_FACE     BBB_AAA 
 1        0           0 
 0        0           0 
 0        0           0 
 0        1           0 
 0        0           0 
 0        0           1
```

I tried `dplyr's` spread() function. But there I got the issue that I spread the data in many, many columns (instead of only the columns containing 'AAA' pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(i1 = as.integer(str_detect(Column_1, "AAA")), 
         rn = row_number()) %>%
  spread(Column_1, i1, fill = 0) %>% 
  select(matches("AAA"))
#   AAA AAA_FACE BBB_AAA
#1   1        0       0
#2   0        0       0
#3   0        0       0
#4   0        1       0
#5   0        0       0
#6   0        0       1
```

---

It can be made a bit more efficient by `replace`ing the other values to `NA` and then do the `spread`

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(i1 = as.integer(str_detect(Column_1, "AAA")),
         Column_1 = replace(Column_1, !i1, NA), 
         rn = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(Column_1, i1, fill = 0) %>% 
  select(matches("AAA"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using basic R code:

Your data

```
db<-data.frame(Column_1=c("AAA","B","BBB","AAA_FACE","CCC","BBB_AAA"))
```

Identify "AAA" pattern

```
AAA_names<-as.character(db[grep("AAA",db$Column_1),"Column_1"])
```

Output dataframe creation:

```
out<-data.frame(lapply(AAA_names, f<-function(x,y){ return(x == y) }, y=as.character(db$Column_1)))
colnames(out)<-AAA_names
out[,AAA_names] <- lapply(out[,AAA_names], as.numeric)
```

Your output

```
out
  AAA AAA_FACE BBB_AAA
1   1        0       0
2   0        0       0
3   0        0       0
4   0        1       0
5   0        0       0
6   0        0       1
```